# How do I call a test with fixtures in a different process

Tags: pytest

I'm writing tests for a library built on pytorch, and many of the tests need to exercise torch.distributed by running the same function body on different processes and communicating with each other (e.g. using torch.distributed.all_reduce).

I currently have a decorator which wraps a test like so:

```
import inspect

@wrap()
def foo():
    assert true == false

def wrap():
    def fixer(function)
        def replacement():
            torch.distributed.mp.spawn(function, nprocs=2)

        setattr(inspect.getmodule(function), "test_" + function.__name__, replacement)
    return fixer
```

But this doesn't work with pytest fixtures, and I would like to be able to use fixtures. I tried declaring my own `pytest_runtest_call`/`pytest_runtest_protocol` but the test item isn't pickle-able so I'm back to square one. Is there some easy way to do this that minimizes the boilerplate for each test?

Currently tests that need fixtures call `mp.spawn` on another function which contains the actual test body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is not in pytorch or different process but simply in losing the function signature and parameter passing in `wrap`

```
def wrap():
    def fixer(function):
        paramertes = inspect.signature(function).parameters
        @wraps(function)  # this will make pytest pass fixtures to the wrapped function  
        def replacement(*args, **kwargs):
            assert args == tuple()
            args = tuple(kwargs[p] for p in paramertes)  # converting named parameters to positional parameters to pass to `spawn`
            torch.distributed.mp.spawn(function, args=args, nprocs=2)

        setattr(inspect.getmodule(function), "test_" + function.__name__, replacement)
    return fixer


@fixture()
def d():
    return 1


@wrap()
def foo(d):
    assert d == 1
```